# magento talking two much time on zero installation, 500 error is showing in console

Tags: magento2

http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1772552/f53fba11334071f01cf363db363c9e9a
magento talking two much time on zero installation, 500 error is showing in console. I have every thing php7 and mysql 5.6 and all thing, 2.3 gb ram with vps server but not able to  please help me.

Answer (score -1):

Please give proper permission to the magento 2 folder.

Then please enable mod_rewrite.

do this and let me know.

Comment: let me know how can  i unable mode_write in my cpanel

Comment: Put a file in magento root folder info.php . Inside it just write down the code <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: run it from browser to check mod_rewrite is enabled or not ?

Comment: http://fisanti.se/phpinfo.php  please check this sany issue regarding to max file and etc      you can check http://fisanti.se/  magento intsalltion on this server in que

Comment: ;you there? bro

Comment: I think mod rewrite is not enabled in your server. So you have to enable it via ssh console.

Comment: any  syntex for this  i am in my putty with ssh